# Setting a specific location for a floating JToolBar

Tags: java, swing, jtoolbar

I want to set a specific location to a JToolBar when I launch the Application.
Is there any way to set the floating location of a JToolBar on a specific Point on the screen?

I have this code as example which will create a Toolbar and tries to set it floating at Point(300,200), but instead it displays it (floating) at location (0,0).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
    toolbar.add(new JButton("button 1"));
    toolbar.add(new JButton("button 2"));

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    ((BasicToolBarUI) toolbar.getUI()).setFloating(true, new Point(300, 200));

    frame.setSize(350, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the source code of [setFloating(boolean, Point)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicToolBarUI.java#BasicToolBarUI.setFloating%28boolean%2Cjava.awt.Point%29), the `Point` parameter is only used in case of a `false` first parameter, and is used to find the location to dock the toolbar to its original `Container`.

Basically, `floating` being the boolean parameter, it goes like :

`if(floating)`, undock the toolbar and put it in a `Window`, which location corresponds to the internal `floatingX`and `floatingY` variables of `BasicToolBarUI` (the `Point` parameter is not used at all)

`else` , dock it back to the `Container`, using the `Point` parameter to find where to dock it (North, East...).

Fortunately, a method exists to modify the values of `floatingX` and `floatingY` : `setFloatingLocation(int x, int y)`.

So just call this method before calling `setFloating` (to which you may pass a `null` `Point` parameter, since it won't be used anyway).

```
((BasicToolBarUI) toolbar.getUI()).setFloatingLocation(300, 200);
((BasicToolBarUI) toolbar.getUI()).setFloating(true, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

To give the toolbar an absolute layout first you have to set the layout to null like this: `frame.setLayout(null);` Then instead of `((BasicToolBarUI) toolbar.getUI()).setFloating(true, new Point(300, 200));` you can just use `toolBar.setBounds(x,y, width, height);`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(null);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
toolbar.add(new JButton("button 1"));
toolbar.add(new JButton("button 2"));

Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
contentPane.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

toolBar.setBounds(100,100,50,50);

frame.setSize(350, 150);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

}